# GA4 returning Page Path .html

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm a bit of a novice with Google Analytics 4, but in reviewing our GA4 dashboard, I see in the Page and Screens sections, which when set to "Page path and screen class", a list of the top 10 page paths.

In this list are 2 of the same path, however, one includes the .html file extension in the path and the other does not.

Does anyone have any advice as to why this might occur and how to avoid this issue??

Ex:
/landing-page/section-1/page-1
/landing-page/section-1/page-1.html